# Get values from multiple selections in SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a selection box that allows you to select multiple options. I need to access all the selected values with JavaScript - possible a array of values?

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but this has been answered numerous times before on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best way to get an array of the selected values back:

```
$("#mySelect").val(); // Return an array of the selected options values
```

This assumes that `multiple="mutliple"` and `size` is greater than one on the `select` element.

Answer (score 3):

```
var values = [];
$('#my_select option:selected').each(function(i, selected){
    values[i] = $(selected).attr('value');
});
```

Comment: This is the incorrect answer and it will not work. It will look for `select` elements that are selected instead of their options, and if that were fixed, it would return the text content of the `option` not the value.

Comment: I was too quick on the trigger aswell. Actually I could only get your answer to work dcneiner.

Comment: @meep - My solution is now fixed. @dcneiner's solution is by far the best one here.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`$.map`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map):

```
var values = $('#mySelect option:selected').map(function() {
    return this.value; // or $(this).val()
}).get();
```