# how to get value from h:selectManyMenu

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have a question about h:selectManyMenu component in JSF. My problem is that if user has added 10 items in his  h:selectManyMenu item and than selected 3 from the available item list, now i want to get the value of those 3 selected items through some  java script code. 
Any idea?

```
<h:selectManyMenu id="goodsList" style="height:65px;width:60px;" 
                        value="#{itemsBean.attachedItems}" ondblclick="removeAttched(this);">
                        <f:selectItems  value="#{itemsBean.goodsItemsList}" />
                    </h:selectManyMenu>&nbsp;
```

Comment: Check this link. May this will work for you- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584223/how-to-get-value-from-hselectonemenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to call a javascript function:

```
<f:selectItems  value="#{itemsBean.goodsItemsList}" onclick="function(this)" />
```

The `onclick="function(this)"` part of the line will pass the selected object to the function.

You also could use `onblur()`, `ondblclick()`, `onchange()` and you can look at all the attributes [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectManyMenu.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the key part here is that `h:selectManyMenu` renders a plain `<select multiple="multiple" size="1">` HTML element. As long as this is all client-side, you can query DOM element using plain Javascript. Questions about this have been asked and answered numerous times, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749140/785663) is one stating:

```
$('#mySelect').val(); // Return an array of the selected options values
```

The only thing noteworthy is that your `mySelect` id is a *clientId*, so includes your surrounding form id:

```
<h:form id="testF">
  <h:selectManyMenu id="goodsList" ondblclick="callMe()" 
      value="#{itemsBean.attachedItems}">
    <f:selectItems  value="#{itemsBean.goodsItemsList}" />
  </h:selectManyMenu>
</h:form>
<h:outputScript target="body">
  function callMe() {
    var selected = $('#testF\\:goodsList').val();
    selected.forEach(function(val) { console.debug(val); });
  }
</h:outputScript>
```